# How can I trigger event of a hidden element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was watching a [video](https://youtu.be/ML743nrkMHw?si=eFPUY-qJ88jqg62t&t=2047) of someone building an Electron app, and I saw this weird pattern he used to change the state of the file input. He basically has the html code like this:

```
<div class="flex flex-col w-full items-center justify-center bg-grey-lighter">
    <label
      class="w-64 flex flex-col items-center px-4 py-7 bg-white text-gray-500 rounded-lg shadow-lg tracking-wide uppercase border border-blue cursor-pointer hover:text-teal-800"
    >
      <img src="./images/logo.svg" width="32" />
      <span class="mt-2 leading-normal">Select an image to resize</span>
      <input id="img" type="file" class="hidden" />
    </label>
</div>
```

If we take a look at the input tag with `id="img"`, he's put class hidden to it, and the .hidden class is defined to set the display to none.

Yet this is his JavaScript code, which listens for any state change of the file input 'img':

```
const img = document.querySelector('#img');
img.addEventListener('change', () => ...);
```

Weirdly enough, when he clicks somewhere in the label tag, the File selector window pops up on his screen. How is that possible since the input file tag is pretty much hidden?

I was expecting the file selector not to be opened for hidden file input elements.

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't even know about this. So it gets focused and consequently acts as though someone clicked to it?

Comment: Pretty much, it also works if you set `for` on the label to `img` and then you can move `img` outside of the label. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ho97g056/) is a JSFiddle showing that it works when you use `for` and have `img` outside of the label.

Comment: Aside: Did you know that you can make a link directly to a timestamp in a video? https://www.wikihow.com/Link-to-a-Certain-Time-in-a-YouTube-Video

Comment: Please don't post "thanks" comments. Just improve your question, as I have done for you. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

This is not surprising and works simply because the `label` is wrapping the `img`. This is a common technique used to create many interesting UX scenarios. Essentially, the `label` becomes a trigger for some hidden element, which then has a callback on it. Here's a [link to another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49243460/how-to-check-if-a-input-type-button-is-checked/49243766#49243766) of mine that shows how this can be leveraged to create button groups that work like checkboxes and radio buttons, but with those checkboxes and radio buttons hidden and only labels being visible on the page.

`display:none` means the image won't be displayed on the page, but it is still part of the DOM.

Here is the same scenario, just with the simplest code possible. Click the text and see what happens.

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<label>
  click me
  <input type="file" class="hidden">
</label>
```